# Mybatis plugin to use SystemMetaObject. ForObject (source); nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException:

Tags: java, mybatis

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/webapp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'type' in 'class java.lang.Class'] with root cause
```

```
org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'type' in 'class java.lang.Class'

2023-03-31 00:02:16.278 ERROR 13716 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/webapp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'type' in 'class java.lang.Class'] with root cause

org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException:
```

The code is as follows:

```
@Slf4j
@Intercepts(@Signature(type = ResultSetHandler.class,
        method = "handleResultSets",
        args = {Statement .class}))
public class MybatisXXPlugin implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Object intercept(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {

        List<Object> proceed = (List<Object>)invocation.proceed();
        proceed.forEach(this::interceptotD);
        return proceed;
    }

    private void interceptotD(Object obj) {
        if(obj!=null){
            Class<?> soureClass = obj.getClass();
            MetaObject metaObject = SystemMetaObject.forObject(soureClass);
            Stream.of(soureClass.getDeclaredFields()).filter(field ->    
            field.isAnnotationPresent(DBAC.class))
            .forEach(field -> intercepValue(metaObject,field));
        }

    }

    private void intercepValue(MetaObject metaObject, Field field) {

        DBAC annotation = field.getAnnotation(DBAC.class);
        String name = field.getName();
        Object value = metaObject.getValue(name);
        if(annotation != null && String.class == metaObject.getGetterType(name) && value != null){
            metaObject.setValue(name,"********");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Object plugin(Object target) {
        if(target instanceof ResultSetHandler){
            return Plugin.wrap(target, this);
        }
        return target;
    }
}
```

```
@Data
@TableName("a")
@ToString
public class A implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @TableId(value = "id", type = IdType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String hzqs;

    @DBAC
    private Integer type;

}
```

`@DBAC` is the location of the attribute addressed above

Comment: `SystemMetaObject` is an internal utility and  may not be suitable for that job. You should use reflection directly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But I can't figure out why this problem occurs with 'SystemMetaObject'. At this level, I'm intercepting it as a plugin, using 'SystemMetaObject'.
In 'metaObject.getValue(name); 'This one was impossible to find
"type", which aspects should I tackle next?
 ‘type’ ，接下来我应该从哪方面入手解决？

Comment: As you already have [`Field`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Field.html), you can use `get()` and `set()` methods to rewrite the value.

Comment: My careless, forget what has been ignored the 【 SystemMetaobject. Forobject (obj).】
It should not be 【 Class> soureClass = obj.getClass(); 】 It should be Object obj, because I've been ignoring it, and that's a stupid mistake